# How can I get multiple inputs as array or object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to build an object from multiple inputs. When I have for example this structure:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="This is a text"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.44"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Pig"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.22"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Chicken"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.11"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Lava"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get every row as single entry in my object so that each object entry has a key `text` and a key `float`:

```
const entry = {
    text: "This is a text",
    float: 1.44
};

const result = [
    entry
];
```

I have absolutely no idea how to get all my inputs in a structure like this (This is needed to perform an AJAX request to my backend). Maybe can you give me a hint or idea how I can get this done? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wrap in a form and use serialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in js you could do like:

```js
let result = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row')].map( div => ({text:div.children[0].value, float:div.children[1].value}) )

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="This is a text"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.44"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Pig"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.22"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Chicken"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.11"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Lava"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` with a for loop and set the values in the object accordingly

```js
var arr=document.querySelectorAll(".row")

var array=[];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
var obj={}
obj.entries=arr[i].querySelector(".text").value
obj.float=arr[i].querySelector(".float").value
array.push(obj)
}
console.log(array)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="This is a text"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.44"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Pig"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.22"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Chicken"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.11"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Lava"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = [];
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");

for (let row of rows) {
  var tdata = row.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].value;
  var fdata = row.getElementsByClassName('float')[0].value;
  var entry = {
    text: tdata,
    float: parseFloat(fdata)
  };
  result.push(entry);
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
console.log(result);
```

```css
#result{
  background: #dedede;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="This is a text"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.44"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Pig"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.22"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Chicken"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1.11"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input class="text" name="text" value="Lava"/>
        <input class="float" name="float" value="1"/>
    </div>
</div>
<pre id="result">test</pre>
```